# Python: JSON get value from list of dictionaries, or print something if list is empty

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON response I get from a web API. The problem is that the JSON can have varying levels, which translate into dictionaries of dictionaries, with an occasional list in the mix.
Example (this works):

```
for r in json_doc['results']:
    yield r.get('lastLoginLocation',{}).get('coordinates',{}).get('lat',{})
```

Can I do the same thing when a list of dictionaries is in there? I'd like it to return the specified key value from the first dictionary in the list if the list is populated, or return '{}' if the list is empty.

Example (this does NOT work)

```
   yield r.get('profile',{}).get('phones',{})[0].get('default',{})
```

Comment: Presumable `phone` is a `list` so should default to `[]`, and no there is no `get` with default for `list`. Wrap it in a `try: ... except: yield {}`. Then you can just `try: yield r['profile']['phones'][0]['default']; except: yield {}` (Though you probably want to narrow it down to `KeyError` or `IndexError`)

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply in `get('phones') use a list with one empty dict as default, ie:

```
yield r.get('profile',{}).get('phones',[{}])[0].get('default',{})
```

Note that this will still break with an `IndexError` if `r["profile"]["phones"]` is an empty list. You could get around using a `or`, ie:

```
yield (r.get('profile',{}).get('phones',[{}]) or [{}])[0].get('default',{})
```

but it's getting really messy (and builds two empty dicts and lists for no good reason), so you'd probably be better with more explicit code, cf Pankaj Singhal's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is quite suboptimal, since a missing `profile` key in the root dictionary does not terminate the search, but continues further on *unnecessarily*. There obviously would not be any keys in an empty dict.

You could instead use a `try/except`:

```
def get_value(container, keys=None)
    if keys is None: 
        raise ValueError

    for r in container:
        item = r
        for i in keys:
            try:
                item = item[i]
            except (IndexError, KeyError):
                yield {}
                break
        # finished cleanly
        else:
            yield item
```

---

```
get_value(json_doc['results'], keys=['profile', 'phones', 0, 'default'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This `get_nested` helper function might be what you want. I used a similar technique in some XML parsing code in the past. It removes the
implementation from obscuring what your code is actually trying to achieve.

```
from contextlib import suppress

def get_nested(list_or_dict, keys, default={}):
    """Get value from nested list_or_dict using keys. If the current
    level is a dict, lookup the current key. If the current
    level is a list, lookup current key in the first element of the
    list. Return default for any errors.
    """

    def get(item, key):
        if hasattr(item, 'get') and key in item:
            return item[key]
        raise KeyError

    for key in keys:
        with suppress(KeyError):
            list_or_dict = get(list_or_dict, key)
            continue
        with suppress(IndexError, KeyError):
            list_or_dict = get(list_or_dict[0], key)
            continue
        break
    else:
        return list_or_dict
    return default
```

Your code to call it would be like this:

```
for r in json_doc['results']:
    yield get_nested(r, ('lastLoginLocation', 'coordinates', 'lat'))
    yield get_nested(r, ('profile', 'phones', 'default'))
```